# How to change CSS for SELECT dropdown component in react ant design?

Tags: html, reactjs, css, drop-down-menu

I want to change CSS for dropdown options.

```
<Select
      showSearch
      placeholder="Select a Person"
      className="NameList"
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      value = {this.state.value}
      optionFilterProp="children"
      filterOption={(input, option) => option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
    >
      {this.renderOptions()}
    </Select>


renderOptions() {
return this.props.names.map((v) => {
  return <Option value={v.id}>{v.vehicleno}</Option>
})
```

}

here I'm using separate CSS file:

```
.NameList .ant-select-selection{
border: none;
border-radius:0px;
width: 150px}
```

I'm getting output as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R31TH.png)

I want to make dropdown options look like this:

[image]

Comment: Without an output we cannot help you. What is the HTML structure of the select ? I guess there are some `ul` and `li` involved or divs ? and what is the result of your ' tried ' code ?

Comment: Added description which you asked. There is option tag in renderOptions() function. Also added how my output looks.